# nginx proxy_cache_key using regex

Tags: regex, http, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I am trying to match specific parts of `$uri` using `proxy_cache_key` in nginx 1.12 for these requests where different file names (with no arguments) actually have the same file contents. :(

```
2018-04-02T21:25:37+00:00  MISS /bein1/1/media_w1751476191_2333.ts
2018-04-02T21:25:37+00:00  MISS /bein1/1/media_w2137194067_2333.ts
2018-04-02T21:25:38+00:00  MISS /bein1/1/media_w1023873154_2333.ts
```

I have tried the following:

```
location ~ ^/bein1/(.*)/media_(.*)_(.*).(ts)$ {
    proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60s;
    proxy_cache_key "/bein1/$1/media_$3.ts";
    proxy_pass http://origin;
    add_header "X-Hls-Cache-Status" "Cached TS";
}
```

But I still could not match the specified URI.

Can any one can help me please?

Comment: Did you forget add content phase directives, such as proxy_pass or return

Comment: Yes, It's already exists in my config but i didn't added yesterday here, Will add it now>

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the middle filename component (like "w1751476191") can vary and yet the file is the same? In other words, the correct file is determined only by the "1" and the "2333" components?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
location ~ ^/bein1/([-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+)/media_([-_a-zA-Z0-9/]+)_([0-9]+).ts$ {
   proxy_cache_key "/bein1/$1/media_$3.ts";
   proxy_cache_valid 200 302 60s;
   proxy_pass http://origin;
}
```